# How to get all element(Like: UiLabel,UITextfield) from superview and set the label text color and textfield placeholder color

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uilabel

**I have problem to set UITextfield placeholder color and UIlabel Text color**

[image]

1. We can see what i need in the given screen.

> Here is the code i am using to identify the UILabel and UITextfield.

```
func processSubviewsNight(of view: UIView) {

        for subview in view.subviews {

            if subview is UITextField {
                if let textField : UITextField = subview as? UITextField {
                    textField.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
                      textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueColor()
                }
            }

            if subview is UILabel {
                if let label : UILabel = subview as? UILabel {
                    label.textColor = UIColor.white
                }
            }

            if subview is UIButton {
                if let button : UIButton = subview as? UIButton {
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }
                  processSubviewsNight(of: subview)
           }
    }
```

3. Problem is that UITextfield Placeholder and UIButton text go inside the UILabel loop and change UITextfield placeholder color same as UIlabel text color

Comment: Try, else if { } loop instead of if { }

Comment: Printing description of subview:
<UITextFieldLabel: 0x7fef6dc0bfc0; frame = (0 12; 250 17); text = 'Enter Your task'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60000009f7c0>>    ...... The text 'Enter Your task' is the placeholder of UITextfield but this text goes in the UILabel loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `processSubviewsNight(of: subview)` in else condition. Otherwise textfield's subviews will be passed to this method.

```
func processSubviewsNight(of view: UIView) {

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if let lbl = view as? UILabel {
                label.textColor = UIColor.white
            } else if let textField = view as? UITextField {
                textField.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
                textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueColor()
            } else if let button = view as? UIButton {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            } else{
                processSubviewsNight(of: view)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through all subviews and check respective type to change its properties.

```
for subview in view.subviews {

        if let textField = subview as? UITextFiled {

            textFiled.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueColor()
            //set properties

        } else if let button = subview as? UIButton {

            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            //set properties

        } else if let label = subview as? UILabel {

            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            //set properties
        }
    }
```

Comment: <UITextFieldLabel: 0x7fef6dc0bfc0; frame = (0 12; 250 17); text = 'Enter Your task'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60000009f7c0>>    ...... The text 'Enter Your task' is the placeholder of UITextfield but this text goes in the UILabel loop

Comment: Actually placeholder label is contained in UITextFiled so you can get using `_placeholderLabel.textColor`...and changes the color.